# How to set User-Agent for Proxy for requests targeting HTTPS?

Tags: java, proxy, httpurlconnection

The IT of a customer uses a Squid-Proxy to filter the requests to the outside deciding by the User-Agent of the request. Obviously the User-Agent for the request to the Proxy.

I use URL.openConnection() and the resulting HttpURLConnection for this:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
```

Now, for HTTP-URLs this is no problem, as the request to the proxy is the same as to the targeted server. But with HTTPS-URLs Java creates the CONNECT-request to the Proxy without the User-Agent.

How can the User-Agent for the CONNECT-request be set?

Note: this is done from inside a servlet, so setting the user-agent through http.agent-setting would set it for all servlets inside the Tomcat, which should use differing User-Agents.